# FW: Unexpected result upon unnamed registration of the same mapTo with different mapFrom with injectedProperties

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

We are seeing unexpected behavior from Unity when registering the same concrete class to different unnamed instances. In this scenario, the registrations appear to interfere with each other in unexpected ways.

- We provide a framework to other applications where we want to inject
  different interfaces (i.e. different views on a common concept) with
  potentially the same class that may be initialized in different ways,
  either with different injected parameters and/or different values.
  When the framework uses the class via one interface it can expect
  potentially different behavior than when it uses the class via a
  different interface.We therefore register two interfaces with the
  same mapTo class with different initializations (and potentially
  lifetimes).It is logical to expect that when we register type by
  different interfaces in Unity that they do not interfere with each
  other. This is true for named instances, but not for unnamed
  instances.
- There are three logical outcomes of attempting to
  register different interfaces mapped to the same class:

  1. Exception: during the second registration exception should be throwing. The exception is only expected if we believe this is misuse of the framework; we don’t believe this to be true.
  2. Overwrite: the overwrite could make sense, but the internal representation of the current implementation seems to imply it is not designed to overwrite due to the augmentation of the parameters for the mapTo type. In the example code below we are registering 2 different interfaces mapped to the same class and each of them inject 2 properties. We can see that the value of container.policies.policies( of type ObjectBuilder.SpecifiedPropertiesSelectorPolicy) propertiesAndValues , contains 4 injected properties. In the case of overwriting, we are expecting would expect to see 2 injected properties initialized with values from the second registration. Outcome of this behavior in case of registering several different types mapped to the same type and will inject in each of them some properties with values and some of them not (expecting to be not initialized) , the resolved instance will not have proper initialization of any registered types.
  3. Independent registrations: all registration will be resolved properly , each of them will be injected with correct property values.

The independent registrations are what we expect, but does not work. It appears that the mapTo types are not managed based on the registered type but rather only on the mapTo type and the registered name. We would like to understand what the expected behavior is, and if the current behavior is expected, and if there is a clean way to achieve independent registrations.
Note that we have seen suggestions to name the registrations, but we don’t want to change our framework since it is in use, and generally we don’t want to force applications to conform to named instances for no logical reason.
The code attached demonstrates the unexpected behavior.

```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
    using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;

    namespace TestUnity
    {
        public interface IBaseInterface
        {
            string BaseString { set; get; }
        }

        public interface IChildInterface : IBaseInterface
        {
            string ChildString { set; get; }
        }

        public class ChildClass : IChildInterface 
        {
            public string BaseString { set; get; }
            public string ChildString { set; get; }
        }

        public class ContainerClass
        {
            public IBaseInterface impl { set; get; }
        }

        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var container = new UnityContainer();
                container.LoadConfiguration();

                // the expected result BaseString ="IBaseInterface_BaseString" & ChildString ="IBaseInterface_ChildString"
                // the result is BaseString ="IChildInterface_BaseString" & ChildString ="IChildInterface_ChildString" 
                var iBaseInterface = container.Resolve<IBaseInterface>(); 

                // the expected result BaseString ="IChildInterface_BaseString" & ChildString ="IChildInterface_ChildString" 
                var iChildInterface = container.Resolve<IChildInterface>();

                //We expect test class will be initialize with BaseString ="IBaseInterface_BaseString" & ChildString ="IBaseInterface_ChildString" 
                //but the result is the expected result BaseString ="IChildInterface_BaseString" & ChildString ="IChildInterface_ChildString"
                var testClass = container.Resolve<ContainerClass>("Test");

                //The container.Registrations include both regestered types(IBaseInterface & IChildInterface)
                foreach (var registration in container.Registrations)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(@"RegisteredType :{0} ,MappedToType :{1}", registration.RegisteredType, registration.MappedToType);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

App.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
      </configSections>
      <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
        <alias alias="IBaseInterface" type="TestUnity.IBaseInterface, TestUnity" />
        <alias alias="IChildInterface" type="TestUnity.IChildInterface, TestUnity" />
        <alias alias="transient" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.TransientLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity"/>
        <container>

          <register type="IBaseInterface" mapTo="TestUnity.ChildClass, TestUnity">
            <lifetime type="transient"/>
            <property name="BaseString" value="IBaseInterface_BaseString" />
            <property name="ChildString" value="IBaseInterface_ChildString" />
          </register>

          <register  type="IChildInterface" mapTo="TestUnity.ChildClass, TestUnity">
            <lifetime type="transient" />
            <property name="BaseString" value="IChildInterface_BaseString" />
            <property name="ChildString" value="IChildInterface_ChildString" />
          </register>


          <register name="Test" type="TestUnity.ContainerClass, TestUnity" mapTo="TestUnity.ContainerClass, TestUnity">
            <lifetime type="transient" />
            <property name="impl" dependencyType="IBaseInterface" />
          </register>

        </container>
      </unity>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - Sorry, but this looks to be a limitation to Unity.

---

I'm not a member of the team that built Unity, so I can only speculate on the expected behavior as it is not explicitly documented for this specific scenario.  But going by precedence with the other behaviors of Unity, I would have expected it to overwrite the previous registration's `InjectionProperty`.

You are correct that the object builder does not consider the registered type when looking up the policies for building up an instance of the object requested to be resolved.  The object builder key is composed of the mapTo type and the name (see [NamedTypeBuildKey](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/blob/master/source/Unity/Src/ObjectBuilder/Utility/NamedTypeBuildKey.cs)).  The way this key is created is integral to the internals of Unity's Object Builder.  Attempting to add the registered type to this key in the pipeline would be much more customization than you would want to tackle.  And I can't think of another way to introduce your desired behavior of independent registration based on the registered type (besides different concrete classes or multiple named registrations).